# Executing snakemake workflow without a Snakefile

Tags: python, r, snakemake

I am using R and reticulate library to run some python code in a mainly R project.  My goal is to somehow wrap a snakemake workflow in an R script so that the Snakefile uses the same environment as the rest of R code. If it was a regular script instead of a  Snakefile, it would be possible to do so with reticulate, however I have not yet succeeded in converting a Snakefile to a python script. I am aware of the option to snakemake '--print-compilation' which compiles the Snakefile to a python script, but I have not been able to run it successfully even with a minimal example.

Has anyone had any luck with running snakemake purely from python environment?

Comment: I never work with R so I am not entirely sure how environments with R work, but my guess would be that if you call a system command (snakemake) through R it is executed in the same environment as R currently is. What happens if you try that?

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande My case is quite complicated. The snakefile would execute R code too, so _that_ R code needs to run in the same R environment as the code that calls snakemake .Currently my snakefile does multiple calls to Rscript, which create many separate R environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the unlikely case I understood your problem, a solution could be to pass between one snakemake rule and another an R session saved as an image. In this way different rules would share the same environment. For example:

```
rule all:
    input:
        'stuff.txt',
        'plot.pdf',

rule one:
    input:
        rdata= config['rdata'], # This may come from outside snakemake
    output:
        rdata= 'step2.Rdata',
    run:
        R(r"""
        load('{input.rdata}')
        x <- 1:10
        # More stuff in R...
        save.image('{output.rdata}')
        """)

rule two:
    input:
        rdata= 'step2.Rdata',
    output:
        stuff= 'stuff.txt',
        plot= 'plot.pdf',
    shell:
        R(r"""
        load('{input.rdata}')
        # ...
        write.table('{output.stuff}')
        """)
```

Execute as `snakemake ... --config rdata=my_input.Rdata`. For the `R()` function see [scripting-with-r](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v3.11.0/snakefiles/utils.html#scripting-with-r). Note that, as far as I can tell, snakemake is designed to be run as a command line program rather than as a library inside another script.

(If you post a brief example of your problem you may get better answers)

Comment: Yeah, a brief example in this case didn't seem to be possible, so sorry for the vagueness. However, your proposal really makes sense and might solve my problem. Saving the whole environment into Rdata files just didn't cross my mind, while it seems to be an almost ideal solution. Thank you.